Can we impose a total ordering on planar graphs with a maximum vertex degree?
I have a set of fully connected undirected planar graphs with a maximum vertex degree of 3. I would like to be able to index them by producing a unique key for each graph (or even a unique key per planarization of a graph) which can be used to give them a total ordering. (A well-ordering would be even better, and I think ai can transform any total-ordering into a well-ordering, but if that is for some reason impossible, a total ordering is sufficient for my needs.) Could be an injection onto integers, or reals, or lexically-orderable sequences, or whatever; details don't matter as long as, for any new graph (with its planarization), I can determine whether it is "greater" or "lesser" than any graph already in the set, and thus find a unique position at which to insert it into the ordered set.
It does not need to be practical to generate a graph from its indexing key, although that property would be useful.
I can get a trivial partial ordering by comparing vertex counts and then edge counts (or vice-versa), but that obviously results in large subsets of confusable graphs which share both counts but have totally different topology.
Is there a known way of doing this? Or previously unknown way that someone smarter than me can suggest?

Let your collection of graphs be $\{G_i = (V_i, E_i):1\leq i \leq N\}$. Then define $V=\cup_{i=1}^N V_i$, and arbitrarily label the vertices in $V$ as $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$.
You can then order the graphs lexicographically. So $G_i < G_j$ means that

The word $v_{i,1}v_{i,2}\cdots v_{i,|V_i|}$ precedes the word $v_{j,1}v_{j,2}\cdots v_{j,|V_j|}$ or, if those two words are identical (meaning that $V_i = V_j$) then
The word $u_{i,1}v_{i,1}\cdots u_{i,|E_i|}v_{i,|E_i|}$ precedes the word $u_{j,1}v_{j,1}\cdots u_{j,|E_j|}v_{j,|E_j|}$.


This is of course an ordering on labeled graphs; if we want to handle unlabeled planar graphs, the problem becomes more challenging.

I do in fact need an ordering on unlabeled graphs; assigning a labeling isn't inherently a problem, but the labeling needs to be consistent at least for a pairing of a graph and a particular embedding. I was hoping that between the domain being limited to planar graphs, of a low maximum degree, and sensitive to choice of embedding, the problem would become tractable.

Cool. I suggest you add unlabeled to your question.

Just the condition of bounded degree can save us here. We can efficiently find a canonical labeling for such graphs, which reduces us to the labeled case.
